Transposing live works through USB but not through midi cables
Yesterday I was recording in my home studio and I found that, after having recorded several times my digital piano in GarageBand with the track in mute while using it transposed (to be able to hear the right thing when playing along with the other tracks) through midi cable connected to a Presonus USB96, that my older keyboard, connected directly to my Mac, had transpose working live perfectly fine, not requiring a muted track while recording.
The USB96 doesn’t have a USB input. So I’m wondering if I should connect the digital piano also directly to the computer through USB. There’s no latency for either. I don’t see any reason to assume I should midi cables. Does anyone have experience with that?

"I don’t see any reason to assume I should midi cables" you should WHAT with midi cables? explaining clearly what you mean is critical for us to understand your needs. Do check the rest of your post.
